# I need to get 5 random elements from array (array I am fetching from API using service ) in angular

Tags: angular, sorting, service

I need to get 5 random elements from array (array I am fetching from API using service) in angular.
I am getting random indexes  but getting undefined data corresponding to that index.
Filter and map  I have used.
Below is my code. Can anybody help me to achieve that?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.name = localStorage.getItem("name")!;
    this.getAllQuestions();
    this.getCountries();
    this.getThreeRandomCountries();
    this.startCounter();
  }
  getAllQuestions() {
    this.questionService.getQuestionJson()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.questionList = res.questions;

      })
  }

  getThreeRandomIds() {
    const randomIds: any[] = [];
    while(1) {
      this.randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      if (randomIds.includes(this.randomId)) {
        continue;
      } else {
        randomIds.push(this.randomId);
        if (randomIds.length === 5) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return randomIds;
  }
  
  getCountries(){
    this.questionService.getCountriesJson().subscribe(res=>{
      this.response=res
      console.log(this.response)
this.countries=this.response.data

    })
  }





getCountry(name: string) {
 
 return this.countries.filter((country:any) => country.name=== name)[0];
 

}

getThreeRandomCountries() {
  const randomIds =this.getThreeRandomIds();
  console.log(randomIds)
  // console.log(this.countries)
  this.threeRandomCountries = randomIds.map((name)=> this.getCountry(name));
 
  console.log(this.threeRandomCountries)
  
}
```

Comment: **What have you tried? Have you ever done any research?** A simple search on "JavaScript non-duplicate random number" will literally provide you with a solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array =[3,6,1,9,10,22,54,67]
function randomFiveNumber(min, max) { 
  if(max< 5){
    return false;
  }
  let ranges =[]
  for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
    const val =Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
    if(ranges.includes(val)){
        i--;
    }
    else{
     ranges.push( array[val])
     }
     }
     return ranges
} 
// Log to console
console.log(randomFiveNumber(0,array.length))
```

i think this is a quite working solution for you know let me know if it works for you